# wordpress url issue after migration

Tags: wordpress

we have installed the WordPress in a vpn server without internet, after that exported the WordPress file there using all in one wp migration plugin. Now we have to access the server using public IP with internet but we are unable. Even we have changed the private ip with public ip in wp-config.php and in database wp_options table also. still the server and /wp-admin is not accessible over internet.

Is there anything that need to be done here or I am making any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename temporarily security related plugins, if installed
2. Check your .htaccess file
3. Make sure if you renamed the wp-admin URL using any plugin
4. Please post error message or screenshot, URL here
5. Are you able to access home page and any other pages.